# Issue with Script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

We have a script which is checking and sending an alert if process goes down. For some reason it is not capturing it properly for all the users and not sending the alerts in all scenarios. 
Please suggest what could be the problem.

Environments – uatwrk1, uatwrk2, uatwrk3 ------- uatwrk100
ServerName   - myuatserver
Process to be checked -  Amc/apache/bin/httpd

Script is :

```
#!/bin/ksh
  i=1
  while (( i<=100 ))
  do
    myuser=uatwrk$i
    NoOfProcess=`ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $myuser | grep "Amc/apache/bin/httpd" | wc -l`
    if [[ $NoOfProcess -eq 0 ]]
       then
          echo "Amc process is down, sending an alert"
          # Assume sendAlert.ksh is fine
          ./sendAlert.ksh  
    else
       echo "Amc process is running fine" >> /dev/null
    fi
  (( i+=1 ))
  done
```

Comment: It looks like `sendAlert.ksh` will be executed 100 times as quickly as possible, then the wrapper terminates. I would have expected an infinite loop.

Comment: use `grep -w $myuser`. You may get running fine for user1 if user10 is running

Comment: Do you want an alert for each user without htpd, or just 1 alert when not all users have httpd processes?

Answer (score 0):

I think @Mahesh already indicated the problem in a comment.
When you only want to have a mail once, you can count the users running a httpd process. The backslash in the following command is for avoiding `grep -v grep`.

```
ps -ef | grep "A\mc/apache/bin/httpd" | cut -d " " -f1 | grep "^uatwrk"| sort -u | wc -l
```